# Do I need a top-level sizer on my wxWidgets frame-based app?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am undergoing a number of tutorials on wxWidgets and found that I must add a `wxPanel` to my main *frame* in order to get a Windows native-like background, instead of the ugly dark-grey that it defaults to.

Now, the [WxSmith tutorial: Hello world](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxSmith_tutorial:_Hello_world) states that a `wxBoxSizer` is the first control that should be added to the main frame. Then goes the `wxPanel`, and then *another* sizer where I'll put my controls (text, buttons, etc).

I'm failing to understand the need for the first sizer. For me it would make more sense to have the following hierarchy: Frame -> Panel -> Sizer -> Controls.

So, **do I really need to add a top-level sizer to my frame, *before* the panel?**

Note: The only purpose of the `wxPanel` is to give my window a light-grey background.

**Edit** In fact, I only get what I want (light background color for the entire window) if the panel is the frame's first and only child control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need a sizer for the panel because `wxFrame` automatically resizes its *only* child to fill its entire client area, just because it's such a common case.

The purpose of `wxPanel` is not only to give you the "correct" background, but also to provide correct keyboard navigation among your controls. And the reason it is decoupled from `wxFrame` is that some frames don't contain controls but are used as e.g. canvases, in which case the panel would be unnecessary.

Finally, don't be confused: sizers are *not* controls, they are associated with a window and, in turn, contain (some of) the window children, but are not controls themselves.

Comment: Thanks, very clear. Btw, do you have any clue of why the tutorial I mentioned leads the user to add a sizer first?

Comment: No, sorry, I had never seen this tutorial before. Notice that as it's a wiki, you should be able to correct/simplify it now yourself.